# Statement fails to show or hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

So I have this JS script for hiding category (div class=category):

http://jsfiddle.net/QN9cb/1/

Script should be working like this - Visitors who visit www.example.com can't see category, but visitors with link www.example.com/?access=beta can see that 'Beta' category.

I used jQuery .show() and .hide() to show and hide div category but category is not showing. Can't solve this for days already, my mind is blocked. Any suggestion?

```
//this line of code hides category
$("*").find("[data-categoryname=Beta]").hide();

//this line of code shoud show category, but it isn't showing it
$("*").find("[data-categoryname="+grabAccess()+"]").show();

//see link above for full script
```

PS. script is using cookies so the visitors don't have to enter every time /?access=beta

PS2. Only way to test script is to download it, because you need to enter /?access=beta in URL and you can't do that via JSFiddle

Comment: I guess it is working in Chrome! :) I cannot find anything in the right side...

Comment: Do you call the above JS when the DOM is loaded? (document is ready)

Comment: Check what grabAccess() is returning.

Comment: This happens when I refresh page: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqf0h4w8j02wg8h/js.mp4

It shows and than hides :/

Answer (score 1):

My best guess (without having set up a local test of your code) is that your rather odd selector is failing. The `find()` method searches inside an element, not through an array of previously selected elements. If anything, you'd use `filter()` with your current code.

Rather than this:

```
$("*").find("[data-categoryname=Beta]").hide();
```

I'd simply do

```
$("[data-categoryname=Beta]").hide();
```

or, assuming a div element:

```
$("div[data-categoryname=Beta]").hide();
```

The selector, as you have it, searches the descendants of every element on the page. That's a terribly inefficient way to approach this, and may be resulting in timeouts or other issues.

Comment: Nice advice. I tried with $("div[data-categoryname=Beta]").hide(); and $("div[data-categoryname="+grabAccess()+"]").show(); but same thing. This happens when I refresh page: dropbox.com/s/xqf0h4w8j02wg8h/js.mp4 It's killing me cause I know that probably one tiny thing is missing to complete the puzzle